# activity is creates twice for no apparent reason

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am writing an application running on my custom device (marshmallow based). the general idea is to prompt a user dialog to enter some information at boot and send it to my server. once the information is successfully sent I update the shared preferences that the information was sent and the dialog will not be prompt anymore.

as always I check to see if the needed permissions are present (read phone state for IMEI and sim info), if not I create an activity that requests permissions and on result starts the user dialog activity. if permissions already exist I create the dialog activity straight from the boot receiver.

however, for some reason, sometimes the permissions activity is created twice (I made sure the boot receiver is only triggered once). this causes as expected the user dialog to be shown twice for no reason. does anyone know how can I solve this? thank you.

here is a code snippet for the boot receiver (the only place where the permissions activity is started).

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

SharedPreferences mPrefs;
boolean wasUpdated;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.v("car_num", "got boot receiver");
    mPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("car_num", MODE_PRIVATE);
    wasUpdated = mPrefs.getBoolean("is_num_updated", false);
    if (!wasUpdated) {
        Log.v("car_num", "first time - asking for car num");
        if (UtilityFunctions.checkPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {
            Log.v("car_num", "we have permission lets ask for car num");
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClassName("com.mgroup.carnumberapp", "com.mgroup.carnumberapp.MainActivity");
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
            Log.v("car_num", "main activity started");
        } else {
            Log.v("car_num", "no permission - so requesting");
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClassName("com.mgroup.carnumberapp", "com.mgroup.carnumberapp.PermissionActivity");
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.putExtra("from", "boot receiver");
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    } else {
        Log.v("car_num", "car number already updated - doing nothing");
    }

}
```

}

edit:
I tried adding

```
 android:launchMode = "singleTop"
```

however, it happened again.
here is my manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/MGServiceTheme">
    <service
        android:name=".SendDetailsService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"></service>

    <activity android:name=".PermissionActivity"
        android:launchMode = "singleTop"/>

    <receiver
        android:name=".BootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Add logging and see if the boot receiver is being called more than once.

Comment: I did as stated above. it's not. furthermore, as you can see I added an extra parameter for the intent "from" and in both instances it came from - "boot receiver"

Comment: How are you testing this?

Comment: in the logs, I get once the log "got boot receiver" and twice the logs from permissions activity.

Comment: Well, user may have clicked HOME and then returned to the permissions activity, or maybe some other activity is started also at boot time. Hard to determine from here. Generally speaking it sounds OK what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest do `android:launchMode="singleTop"` for an activity
like

```
  <activity android:name=".MapActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I tried your solution, but the problem persists. thank you anyway.

Comment: Try using the intent which is provided in `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` rather than creating your own intent!